# How do I Store 6 integers from Scanner Console into a Set

Tags: java, arrays, set, java.util.scanner, hashset

I know this is simple. How would I take input from my console and store the input into a Set that can later be used to be returned on a Method. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class InputConsole {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(6);
    int[] numbers = new int[6];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

        System.out.print("Please enter number ");
        numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
        {

        }

    }
}
}
```

I am using and Array just to test with. The Array is set to 6 so if I type 6 numbers in the console it will stop. I have instantiated the HashSet but I don't know how to go about storing the numbers from the console into it.

Comment: Why do you add it to the array first instead of adding it directly to the set?

Comment: ...`s.add(...)` doesn't work?

Comment: how do I add it directly to the set?

Comment: Use `s.add(j)` where j is the number read in from the Scanner. However, be aware that using a `HashSet` will erase duplicates (if they type in the number 5 twice, you'll only find it in the set once) and will erase the order (if they enter 2 4 3 9 8 5, when you iterate through the set it could come out in any order).

Comment: Also, you say you want to "store the input into a Set that can later be used to be returned on a Method" but your Set is a local variable inside your `main` method... you won't be able to return it from another method unless you make it an instance or class variable.

Comment: Thanks for the input I am writing a separate method as apart of a JUnit test.

Answer (score 1):

Use method [**Set::add()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29)

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
{    
    System.out.print("Please enter number ");
    s.add(input.nextInt());
}
```

You don't need `int[]` array
**EDIT:**
Whole *main()*

```
   public static void main(final String ... args) 
   {
      final int inputs = 6;
      final Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(6);
      final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      for (int i = 0; i < inputs; i++) 
      {
         System.out.print("Please enter number #" + (i + 1) + ":");
         s.add(input.nextInt());
      }

      System.out.println("Well done!");
      System.out.println(s);
   }
```

Comment: once I remove int[], do  need to change numbers.length also?

Comment: @cw.prime yes, you should change `numbers.length` -> `6`

Comment: this seems to still be using the array.. when a remove  int[] numbers = new int[6]; is the array still necassary?

Comment: This is perfect. just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class Hashsetdemo
{

     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         HashSet h=new HashSet(6);
         int [] no = new int[6];
         Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

         for (int i=0;i<no.length;i++)
         {
             System.out.println("please enter number");

             h.add(s.nextInt());
         }
         System.out.println(h);
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to help. Some explanation would help noticeably better. Also I don’t think you should use raw types (prefer `HashSet<Integer>` as in the question over just `HashSet`).